# Way to calculate exponent in congruent equation

Tags: modular-arithmetic, logarithms

I want to solve

$$ 5^{x} \equiv 21 \pmod {23} $$

Is there a way to get the $x$ without trial & error?

Comment: Maybe, computing $5^1, 5^2, 5^4, 5^8, 5^{16}\pmod{23}$ by squaring and then trying to "factor" $21$ into product of these. $(5^1, 5^2, 5^4, 5^8, 5^{16})\equiv (5, 2, 4, 16, 3)\pmod{23}$, $21=3\cdot 7\equiv 3 \cdot 30\equiv 3\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 2\pmod{23}$, then $x\equiv 16+16+1+2\pmod{22}$

Comment: $x=22k+13$, with $k\ge0$. See [discrete logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm).

Answer (score 1):

We have $5^{11}\equiv -1\pmod {23}$, because $\left(\frac5{23}\right)=-1$, and also $5^2\equiv2\pmod{23}$ hence
$$
5^{13}\equiv 5^{11}5^2\equiv -2\equiv 21\pmod {23}
$$
And the number $13$ is the smallest because the function $5^x$ is periodic modulo $23$ with period $\varphi(23)=22$.