# Get all values for exponent in congruential equation

Tags: modular-arithmetic, logarithms

I am stuck on an exercise on modular arithmetic.
I found a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1265463/way-to-calculate-exponent-in-congruent-equation), but I don't think it answers my question completely.

My problem is:

> Solve $$ 2^x \equiv 11 \pmod {21} $$
>
> over $\Bbb N$. I know the solution should be $$x = 5 + 6k$$ where $k \in \Bbb N_0$ ($\Bbb N$ with 0 included).

My problem is, that I don't know how they got this solution.

My solution was:

$$ 2^x \equiv 11 \pmod {21} $$
$$(\text{multiply by } 2 \equiv 11^{-1}\pmod{21}) $$
$$2^{x+1}\equiv1\pmod{21}$$

According to [Euler's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), $a^{\phi(n)}\equiv1\pmod{n} \iff gcd(a,n) = 1$. Where $\phi(n)$ is [Euler's Phi Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).

It means that because $gcd(21, 2) = 1$, $$ x+1 = \phi(21)$$

$$\implies x=\phi(21)-1 = 12-1=11$$

Also, $x$ is periodic modulo 21 and its period is $\phi(21) = 12$. My solution therefore is

$$x = 11 + 12k, k\in \Bbb N_0$$

What am I doing wrong? I can get to $x=5$ only by trial & error and I don't know how to get $6k$ as the period at all.

I would like to know how to solve this type of problems in general. If $11^{-1}$ wasn't 2 I wouldn't know what to do at all, because I couldn't join the exponents.

Comment: Euler's theorem doesn't say that $$a^{\varphi(n)} \equiv 1 \pmod{n} \iff \gcd(a,n) = 1$$ The implication is one sided only

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Euler's theorem does not give the smallest exponent for which $a^k\equiv1\bmod n$. That smallest exponent is given by the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) $\lambda(n)$, and $\lambda(21)=6$ (as compared to $\varphi(21)=12$), so we have
$$2^6\equiv1\bmod21$$
This yields $x=11+6k=5+6k$, as desired.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the Carmichael function. However when I try to use it on $$ 3^{2-x} * 2 \equiv 7 \pmod{11} $$ $$ 3^{2-x} \equiv 3^2 \pmod {11} $$ Carmichael function for 11 is 10 (equal to Euler for primes according to Wikipedia) and the result is $2-x \equiv 2 \pmod {10}$ meaning that $x \equiv 0 \pmod {10}$. However, the result should be $x \equiv 0 \pmod 5$.

Comment: @TopperHarley not all the values given by Carmichael are minimal. You have to check for divisors of the Carmichael value as possible minimal exponents.

Comment: I don't really understand why I have to find the divisors of Carmichael (I see it works, I just don't know why). 
Wikipedia says (under  Properties -- Minimality) that if $a^m \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$ for $a$ coprime with $n$, then $\lambda(n)|m$. Meaning I can find $\lambda(n)$ by trying the divisors of $\phi(n)$. However the first paragraph defines the Carmichael function as "the smallest positive integer such that..." already, which (if I understand correctly) in the case of the comment above should result in $\lambda(n) = 5$, which is not true.

Comment: @TopperHarley Carmichael only gives the LCM of the orders of the elements in the mult-group $Z_n^×$. It does not tell about the orders of individial elements, which you have to find by trial and error on divisors of the Carmichael exponent.

Answer (score 0):

By the Chinese remainder theorem the equation is equivalent with the pair of equations $$2^x \equiv 11 \equiv 2 \pmod {3} \text{ and }2^x \equiv 11 \equiv 4 \pmod {7}$$ with, observing that $2^3 \equiv 1 \pmod 7$, solutions $$x \equiv 1 \pmod 2 \text{ and } x \equiv 2 \pmod 3$$

These combine into $x \equiv 5 \pmod 6$